# code running in terminal and not running in shell_exec php script in Mac

Tags: php, linux, macos, xcodebuild, shell-exec

i can build my xcode project through terminal with the following command

```
xcodebuild -project MyDocuments/proj.xcodeproj -scheme scemeapp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -archivePath MyDocuments/app/app.xcarchive archive
```

however when I try to do them same through a php script in xampp htdocs folder I get the following error.

```
sh: 1: xcodebuild: not found
```

the code I tried to run was this:

```
exec("xcodebuild -project MyDocuments/proj.xcodeproj -scheme scemeapp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -archivePath MyDocuments/app/app.xcarchive archive"." 2>&1",$out);
```

var_dump($out);

I've tried adding /usr/bin/xcodebuild instead in the exec() and its still the same problem.
I've tried the command on shell_exec() instead of exec() and it returns a NULL.

this is probably a problem with it not finding the xcodebuild path correctly however I'm confused. Please help.

Comment: Have you got any solution to this

Comment: Have you found the solution? @evorsor

Comment: @Mojo Jojo use command `type sh;ls -l /bin/sh` to see which sh you two env is used.

Answer (score -1):

You could try find where xcodebuild is located, try this command from your terminal:

`whereis xcodebuild`

Sometime it's located at Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin, confirm that by browse that location; if that the case, put the complete path in your function like this:

`exec("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project MyDocuments/proj.xcodeproj -scheme scemeapp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -archivePath MyDocuments/app/app.xcarchive archive"." 2>&1",$out);`

Comment: No, actually that is not the issue I have found the solution myself, xcodebuil location was perfectly fine, the issue is that the shell script is running through cron, and cron is unable to access the keychain. So i replaced cron with mac inbuild scheduler launched, and it works.